# What C2S & S2S connection types regarding XMPP?

Tags: xmpp

I just started using XMPP with tigase implementation. I also have used jabberd2 implementation of XMPP. But i am still not sure what are *C2S* and *S2S* standards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

c2s is a client to server connection and this is just a standard XMPP protocol. s2s is server to server connection and there are a few protocols/extensions to RFC which describe how 2 XMPP servers can communicate with each other.